# Get an instance of all subclasses of a base class in a package

Tags: android, reflection, package, classloader

Suppose I have my Android app's source code packaged this way:

```
src/
   my/
      app/
         Module.java
         ModuleManager.java
         module/
            ModuleA.java
            ModuleB.java
```

where `Module` is:

```
public abstract class Module {
    public abstract void run();
}
```

, `ModuleA` and `ModuleB` extends `Module`:

```
public class ModuleA extends Module {
    @Override
    public void run() { /* do something */  }
}
```

and `ModuleManager` has some helper methods, among which one to retrieve all the `Module`s:

```
public class ModuleManager {

    private final static List<Module> modules;
    static {
        List<Module> tmp= new ArrayList<Module>();
        tmp.add(new ModuleA());
        tmp.add(new ModuleB());
        modules= Collections.unmodifiableList(tmp);
    }

    public static List<Module> getModules(){
        return modules;
    }
}
```

As you can see I manually filled the list of modules in `ModuleManager`. Instead, I would like it to be **automatically** filled with an instance of all the `Module`'s subtypes in the *module* package.

I tried in several ways reflection-based solutions [like this](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4831), which involve the use of `ClassLoader::getResource(String path)` to retrieve every .class file inside the *module* package, but it always returns an empty enumeration. I learnt this is due to the difference between Dalvik's VM and Java SE's one, and its optimized packaging of .class files inside *classes.dex*. I then tried to import the application's apk from */data/app/* with `DexClassLoader` or `PathClassLoader` and unsuccesfully tried their `getResource()` method again. Anyway I think this is not the right direction, and probably this stuff was already hackish/flawed in Java, and it would be even more in Android.

Could you suggest me a way to do that?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this in a build script, after compilation but before dex is called to create classes.dex, run a small script to get the class names in modules folder and write it to say an application.properties file to read from (or strings.xml in resources).

The disadvantage of this is it is not a pure java method you were asking for, the advantage being it will work for 2 or 10+ subclasses. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

What if you add an XML or a Properties with the module classes and you dynamicly created from it... it might goes something like this

```
<modules>
    <module>
    my.app.module.ModuleA
    </module>
    <module>
    my.app.module.ModuleB
    </module>
</modules>
```

Comment: Thank you for mentioning Java's `Property`, I have never messed around with it but it seems an interesting mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution could be to exploit a naming convention on classes' names and retrieve all of them one-by-one with `Class.forName(className)`. In the example I made, if I know that all modules are named sequentially as `ModuleA`, `ModuleB`, `ModuleC` and so on, I can retrieve all of them starting from `ModuleA` and continuing until `Class.forName("ModuleX")` fails. If gaps were allowed but the number of modules was bounded (and very low), an exhaustive search on the entire range could be done.

Of course this could be applied in a very few cases, and at the expense of class' name readability.